# Complex number graph with two equations

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given three complex number $u, v, z$ consider all complex numbers of the form
> $au + bv + cz$ with $a, b, c$ being non-negative real numbers satisfying $a + b + c = 1$. What
> geometric shape is formed by all these points?

I'm not sure how I should even start on this question. Suppose, $a=1,b=0,c=0$ and all its rotations. Then the three points would be $u,v,z$. I think the locus COULD be a triangle with vertices $u,v,z$?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, under given conditions
it's called 
[a convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination)
of points and 
in general
it is indeed 
a triangle with vertices $u,v,z$,
but it also could turn out to be a line segment or even a point (when?).